# Ethernet issues in Linux mint.

Tags: linux, networking, linux-mint, ethernet

After a hardrive crash I installed mint 17 LTS with many attending woes related to lack of drivers (two of my 8 usb ports can actually recognize devices plugged into them). I'm currently attempting to connect to the internet to download any missing drivers, etc.

So far I've discovered that using DHCP, the network manager would show an interminable "connecting" and then disconnect after a few minutes. I edited my /etc/network/interfaces file to read

```
auto lo  
iface lo inet loopback  
auto eth0  
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

and restarted the network manager. DHCP still did the same thing. I tried configuring the IP address manually using an address which I know is not taken (it was what Windows was configured to use on this machine before the hard drive died) and using Google's public DNS. This yielded progress of a sort: The network manager now claims that I'm connected.
However, I can't access anything in a browser, or even ping my DNS server. The error for that is

```
host unreachable
```

After a little googling, I looked at the route command. The output that gave me was:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.2.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.2.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0
```

To my (network semi-literate) eye, this all looks good except that the destination IP address is *not* what I entered in the network manager. I guess I have a two-part question then:
1- Is this discrepancy the cause of the problem?
2- If not, how do I go about finding what is?

Comment: If your router is dosing out IPs by DHCP them the DHCP client in Mint should pick up an IP. When DHCP _was_ working were you getting a default gateway? Was it your router IP? I'm very surprised that a vanilla Mint install that _at least_ picked up your NIC didn't fully codified it automatically... are there any NIC power settings on Mint?